# How to programmatically start a svg filter animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg, svg-filters

i have build a little glow filter in the defs section of a svg snippet in my html page. That filter has an animation inside, that makes that filter slowly fade.

Now i assign that filter to some svg element, let's say, a rectangle. so far so good, works nice.

Problem, the animation starts right away, but i want to control, when it starts, like when i call a specific function in javascript.

Now i thought, i set the begin of the animation to "indefinite" and then call beginElement() on the animation. But how do i access the animation dom element within the filter, which is assigned to my svg rectangle via url("#myFilterID") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it an id attribute and then call document.getElementById to retrieve it is probably easiest.

Comment: ok, easy in the end. I was not aware, that it is not possible to control a filter "instance", because there is no "instance". Means, if you assign the same filter to multiple elements and you change the filter, all elements are affected, which i did not know.